# Rails 3.2 ajax example with params in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

How to create ajax in next example:

In controller:

```
def index
    if params[:p] == "one"
        @record = "Hello, 1!"
    elsif params[:p] == "two"
        @record = "Hello, 2!"
    else
        @record = "something else"
    end
end
```

In view (hellos controller, index action):

```
<%= link_to "One", hellos_path(:p => "one") %>
<%= link_to "Two", hellos_path(:p => "two") %>
<%= render :partial => 'record' %>
```

Partial _record.html.erb:

```
<%= @record %>
```

That's all. All actions in index controller and only params are changing. I don't want to reload full page - only record partial with new controller variable.

How to "AJAXize" it? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- Add :remote => true to your links:

```
<%= link_to "One", hellos_path(:p => "one"), :remote => true %>
```

2- create a view index.js.erb with:

```
$("#your_div").html("<%= render :partial => "record" %>")
```

3- create a div with the id your_div in your index.html.erb. This div will be populated with the @record object.

Comment: In 3rd step, am I need to add something like `<div id="your_div"></div>` and remove `<%= render :partial => 'record' %>` from view?

Comment: You need to create the div like you said. It is up to you if you want to leave the render partial so that default index page will present it.

Comment: Yep, but when I click link, I'm getting "Completed 200 OK", but it's not present in browser :(

Comment: `$("#your_div").html("<%= j render ("record") %>")` this works for me! :) tnx )

Comment: Ok, it's rendering, but without params :( If I'm in index page and clicking on "One" link, I'm getting this from my controller @record = "something else" :(

Comment: Strange, what are you getting in the server log as params when you click the link?

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake, - I've removed params from link and forgot about this:))) Tnx!